# web browser crashes invoking REST for Image Data in Uint8ClampedArray JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, html5-canvas, getimagedata

In my Project, I have multiple Graphs (max 15 of different plots like Bar , Chart , Bubble, Line) that are being plotted using **javascript** (Open/SAP UI-5) in HTML5 below is the code for the same

```
press: function() {
                    var arrCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
                    for(var i=0; i<arrCanvas.length; i++){
                        var canvas = arrCanvas[i];
                        if(canvas.width!==0 && (typeof imageNames[i] !== 'undefined')){
                            var imageDetail = {};
                            var uint8ArrayClamped = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
              imageDetail.byteData = uint8ArrayClamped;
                            imageDetail.title = "graph-"+i;
                            imageDetail.height = canvas.height;
                            imageDetail.width = canvas.width;
                            arrImageByte.push(imageDetail);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

When I pass this arrImageByte to Ajax call the browser (tested on chrome) crashes with "oh snap" message.

while adding below line to the code

```
    press: function() {
                        var arrCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
                        for(var i=0; i<arrCanvas.length; i++){
                            var canvas = arrCanvas[i];
                            if(canvas.width!==0 && (typeof imageNames[i] !== 'undefined')){
                                var imageDetail = {};
                                var uint8ArrayClamped = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
//I belive somwhow This does the trick
                  imageDetail.byteData = [].slice.call(uint8ArrayClamped);
                                imageDetail.title = "graph-"+i;
                                imageDetail.height = canvas.height;
                                imageDetail.width = canvas.width;
                                arrImageByte.push(imageDetail);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Copying the unit8ArrayClamped into another empty array does the trick, now the code work and REST is being called, I wonder why this is happening? 
but again copying such a huge data into another takes time and for multiple graphs, it takes almost 6-7 seconds, how to reduce this to minimal?

Is there another approach besides copying the byte array into another new array?

Comment: JSON does not support typed arrays. Either send a `FormData` object with each typed array encompassed in a `Blob` or continue creating normal arrays from the typed arrays. `Array.from(uint8ArrayClamped)` would be more canonical than `[].slice.call(uint8ArrayClamped)` for that.

Comment: Also if you choose to send a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it would save bandwidth (and processing on the server) to get the data from [`canvas.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) though you'll have to deal with asynchronous code to do that.

Comment: @downvoters may I know the reason?